# Cross country development, change IP address

Tags: geolocation, ip-address

I am developing sites that will be used in various different countries. The code looks at the originating ip address to determine where they are coming from. I change currency etc based on this.

My problem is testing the functionality in the browser. I have had a look at the geolocator tools in firefox and chrome but these don't change the ip address to the country.

Are there any tools that I can use, preferably without installing something, whereby I can set the ip address to be coming from a different country? I have tried setting the proxy values in the internet options but this doesn't seem to work either.

Thanks

Comment: How are you resolving IP address to country? Are you calling an external web service?

Comment: yes. it's actually an api inside of Kentico. Trying to test the logic but I can only do it in code but I want to test it from an ip because the code fudge works but the ROI users are reporting it isn't

Answer (score 0):

There are several proxy services that will allow you to accomplish your goal.

You can use the Tor Browser / Onion Router proxy for free. Here is a video that shows you how to choose your country.  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5iLCgRHp_2k